# Alterar cor do texto e do background ToolTip

Tags: java, swing

Como posso alterar a cor de background e do texto de um ToolTip? Já fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155124/how-to-change-tooltip-colour) um trecho de código mas não consigo alterar. As cores mantêm-se sempre as padrão do NetBeans. Alguma sugestão?

Coloquei o seguinte código no construtor da minha classe:

```
     UIManager.put("ToolTip.foreground", Color.BLACK);
     UIManager.put("ToolTip.background", Color.GREEN);
     ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setInitialDelay(0);
     ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(1500);
     jFormattedNIPC.setToolTipText("teste");
```

**Atualização:**

Utilizar HTML nas propriedades do campo na secção toolTipText. A cor consegui mudar bem, mas o background fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A cor de background não preenche o 'balão' por completo.
*Cógido utilizado:* `<html><p style='background-color:blue; color:white;'>teste</p></html>`

Comment: Alguns elementos do swing aceitam HTML no texto. Por exemplo numa Label você pode colocar algo assim no texto: `"<html>Palavra em <strong>negrito</strong>.</html>"`. Tentou colocar isso no teu tooltip?

Comment: Não usei qualquer tipo de HTML no meu código. vou tentar esse. Mas a nível de cores qual seria o código? É que não estou muito por dentro de HTML. Desde já obrigado! FUNCIONA O NEGRITO !! :) preciso das cores para background e texto :)

Comment: Mudar a cor do texto já consegui, falta-me para o background do tooltip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solução 1

Alguns elementos do swing aceitam HTML no texto. Por exemplo numa `label` você pode colocar algo assim no texto: `"<html>Palavra em <strong>negrito</strong>.</html>"`.

No seu caso podes fazer assim:

```
"<html><body style=\"background-color:#d8d8ff;\"><center><br>TESTETETESTE</center></body></ht‌​ml>";
```

Porém, como apontado pelo autor da pergunta, esta solução não resolve perfeitamente o problema. Ele não deixa o fundo completamente preenchido com a cor.

## Solução 2

Você pode criar um ToolTip customizado para o componente:

```
class MyCustomToolTip extends JToolTip {
    public MyCustomToolTip(JComponent component) {
       super();
       setComponent(component);
       setBackground(Color.black);
       setForeground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Então na hora de inicializar um componente, neste exemplo um `jTextField`, faça assim:

```
jTextField1 = new JTextField("teste"){
    @Override
    public JToolTip createToolTip() {
        return (new MyCustomToolTip(this));
    }
};
```

Obs.: se você usa NetBeans podes mudar o tooltip de um componente da seguinte forma:

1. Coloque a classe `MyCustomToolTip` depois do método `initComponents()`;
2. Clique com o botão direito no componente;
3. Vá em Propriedades;
4. Clique na aba Código;
5. Na propriedade Código de Criação Personalizado clique nos `...` e digite o código de criação (no caso um `JTextField`):

   ```
   new JTextField("teste"){ // Pode ser new JLabel, depende do tipo do componente
       @Override
       public JToolTip createToolTip() {
           return (new MyCustomToolTip(this));
       }
   };
   ```
6. Ok.

Comment: Dessa forma não funciona. Tem de ser colocado o código HTML nas propriedades do campo na parte to tooltip.

Comment: <html><font color="red">O seu texto ficará vermelho.</font>.</html>  esse código põe a cor do texto vermelha.

O seu código deve ter algum erro ou então não funciona :S

Comment: Exato. Depois do style tem que por um `=`. Eu tinha posto um `:`.

Comment: tenta assim  `"<html><body style=\"background-color:#d8d8ff;\"><center><br>TESTETETESTE</center></body></html>";`   (só para ajudar, nao sei se é a mesma coisa @Earendul)

Comment: Eu não percebo nada de html. @jsantos1991 o seu código não funcionou :S Earendul esse funciona mas tem um pequeno problema. Vou editar a pergunta e mostrar o que acontece.

Comment: @HugoMachado eu também não pesco lá muito, mas esse código funciona para mim ;) mas ainda bem que o código do Earendul funciona

Comment: Ok, já vou editar a resposta com mais uma solução...

Comment: Editei a resposta. Testei aqui e a solução 2 funcionou melhor que a primeira.

Comment: Tenho sempre um problema com isso que deve ser básico mas não consigo resolver :S Já tentei esse código ontem mas não consegui. Em vez de tar a criar um new JTextField eu quero utilizar num campo que já tenho no meu design. Como faço?

Comment: Você usa NetBeans?

Comment: Sim estou com netbeans. Se a solução do @jsantos1991 funcionou aos dois talvez eu não esteja a por o código bem. Pode colocar a linha de código nas Soluções tambem ?

Comment: @HugoMachado alterei a resposta com o código do jsantos1991. Também coloquei os passos para mudar no NetBeans.

Comment: Não me está a funcionar. Pode Colocar a linha de código do @jsantos1991 nessas soluções? e tudo numa linha só para ver se eu ponho em HTML ? :) EDIT: Já está lá !

Só uma questão, as aspas e o ';' entram no código HTML ?

Comment: @HugoMachado - coloquei lá o código do jsantos1991. No caso da solução 2 lembrou de colocar a classe `MyCustomToolTip` junto ao código? Pode colocar depois do método `initComponents()`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18648/discussion-between-earendul-and-hugo-machado).

Comment: Sim coloquei a classe depois no initComponents e pus o código que me disse no Custom Code nas propriedades e não me funciona :(